# wait for multiple API calls to finish using useAxios custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I use `useAxios` custom hook to avoid the code duplicity as the API I am calling is always the same.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import rest from './rest';     // inside there is a definition of axios.create baseURL...       

const useAxios = (endpoint,queryString) => {

  const [axiosData, setAxiosData] = useState(null);
  const [axiosLoading, setAxiosLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {

    const getRest = async () => {
      setAxiosLoading(true);
      try{
        const sensors  = await rest
        .get('/'+ endpoint + '?' + queryString)
        .then(res => {
          setAxiosData(res.data);
          setAxiosLoading(false);
        });
      }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }

    getRest(); 

  }, [endpoint,queryString])

  return {axiosData, axiosLoading}; 

}
export default useAxios;
```

Here is a part of the code where I call `useAxios` hook.

```
const {axiosData:data1} = useAxios('request1','');
const {axiosData:data2} = useAxios('request2','querystring1');
const {axiosData:data3} = useAxios('request3','querystring2');
```

The problem I am trying to solve is how to wait for all the requests to finish, so it is for sure that all the data are ready.

I know about the `axios.all` and would like to use something like that, but with usage of the reusable code like with `useAxios`.

Side note: there are many useAxios calls through the app, not just the one case I explain here. That is the reason I am trying to reuse it instead using one `axios.all`

**EDIT:**
I might have mentioned that earlier, but there is also another `useAxios (data4)` call in subcomponent which uses data from `data1, data2, data3` and should render another subcomponent as many times as the number of objects contained in `data1`. I am passing the data through Context API and need to make sure the `data1, data2, data3` are available before `useAxios (data4)` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you could do something as simple as

```
if (!data1 && !data2 && !data3) {
  // do something
}
```

Since that code will run any time one of those stat variables changes. Or you could put them all as dependencies on a useEffect().

I suspect folks might steer you toward using a state machine if things are getting complicated. See [useReducer()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)

**Update based on new information**
You're probably aware, hooks must be called in the same order every time. You wrote this question because you're dealing with a code smell and I suspect the most 'correct' answer I can give is to think about how you can refactor the code. Break things up into smaller units and make each unit be responsible for less.

The 'quick bandaid' is to update useAxios() so you can no-op it:

```
const useAxios = (endpoint,queryString,bornReady=true) => {
...
if (bornReady) {
  getRest(); 
}
...
```

By defaulting the new parameter to true, old code will sail on by, but you can use the flag to prevent the hook from running. Here I use the querystring as the flag as well. When you can build the querystring, you're ready to make the rest call. Before that, do nothing.

```
const buildQuery = (data, moreData, soMuchData) => {
  if (!data || !moreData || !soMuchData) {
    return undefined // no queryString for you
  }
  // build and return your query
  return `c=${data.custId}&p=${moreData.numThings}`
}
const {axiosData:data1} = useAxios('request1','');
const {axiosData:data2} = useAxios('request2','querystring1');
const {axiosData:data3} = useAxios('request3','querystring2');
const querystring3 = buildQuery(data1, data2, data3)
const {axiosData:data4, axiosLoading} = useAxios('request4',querystring3, !!querystring3);
```

Do a refactor if you can. Maybe even move those calls to the server so you can make 1 request that returns only the data you need. If you're in a jam, add to the mess as illustrated above.

Comment: `data1`, `data2`, etc. will always be truthy, so that conditional will always evaluate to `true`

Comment: @jsejcksn won't `data1`, `data2` etc. be null?

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal ‍♂️ You're correct. I didn't notice that they are destructured (I was thinking they were the object being returned from the hook.)

Comment: @Dave if I put them as dependencies for useEffect, would not that run three times then? Basically I need to pass them to DataContext and need to make sure that they are complete

Comment: please see edit, which explain the real case more deeply. Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* destructure the `axiosData` property from each object returned by the hook. That way, you can inspect the `axiosLoading` property on every `dataN` value to make a determination of whether or not they're all done, like this:

```js
const data1 = useAxios('request1','');
const data2 = useAxios('request2','querystring1');
const data3 = useAxios('request3','querystring2');

const done = [data1, data2, data3].every(({axiosLoading}) => !axiosLoading);
if (done) {
  // they're all done loading
}
else {
  // at least one is still loading
}
```